# 400 Bad Request when POST-ing to Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

My page has...

```
@page "{candidateId:int}"
```

... and

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Model has...

```
public void OnGet(int candidateId)
{

}

public void OnPost(int candidateId)
{

}
```

GET works fine. Here is my AJAX request..

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Skills/" + candidateId,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {

        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    data: {

        name: 'hi mum'
    },

    success: function (response) {
    },
    failure: function (response) {

        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Browser receives useless error message... 400 Bad Request.

What am I missing?

Comment: The 400 error should come with more info than just that. What is the actual error it shows you?

Comment: I don't think it does with an AJAX call.

Comment: But the server response will contain more information than that. Check the browser debug tools.

Comment: The response tab says, "The response has no data available". It's literally just a number and the word "Bad". :)

Comment: Check the view source of the page. Do you have the `__RequestVerificationToken` hidden input generated ?

Comment: Yes and it’s appearing in the list of request headers.

Comment: Oh, yes that was the issue. The code I copied sets it as a header instead of a value in the forms collection. Thanks.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You are getting a 400 (Bad Request) response because the framework expects the `RequestVerificationToken` as part of the posted request.The framework uses this to prevent possible CSRF attacks. If your request does not have this information, the framework will return the 400 bad request. Your current code is not sending it.

Change the code to this

```
headers:
{
    "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
},
```

This will add a new item with key `RequestVerificationToken` to the request header and the framework should not throw a 400 response when the call is made. (assuming your view code generated the hidden input for the `__RequestVerificationToken` hidden input)

You can make the code more robust by injecting the `IAntiforgery` implementation to the view/page and using the `GetAndStoreTokens` method.

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
{
    return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Model.HttpContext).RequestToken;
}
}
```

and call this `GetAntiXsrfRequestToken` function to get the value in your javascript

```
headers:
{
    "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()'
},
```

You also probably want to use the PageModel's `CandidateId` property to create the url. Something like this

```
url: "/Skills/@Model.CandidateId",
```

Also, you do need to call `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` method explicitly to generate the token input. Having a form with post method with no action attribute value will generate the hidden input for you.

```
<form method="post">
   <!-- your inputs-->
</form>
```

Comment: "You are getting a 400 (Bad Request) response because the framework expects the RequestVerificationToken as part of the posted request." Where in the docs can I find this particular information? Please post a link.

Comment: Had same problem and @Html.AntiForgeryToken() was missing in my form

Comment: What if you need to accept a POST from an external site? A site where we cannot include the antiforgerytoken.

Comment: @mxmissile You can ignore validation of the anti forgery token by decorating your PageModel with `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]`. See more here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification#opting-out

Comment: you saved my say savior.

Comment: I also missing @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in model form in razor pages,

Comment: I found a nice side effect is when using your method, I no longer need to use `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the razor page (and no forms are declared). I assume that is expected?